# Do any distributors pack in bags of 10 or so?

Tags: buying

I want to buy components from places like Farnell, Mouser, etc. But I then want to distribute them in kits, each kit would have maybe 10 of each component; the components are tiny 0603 types.

The problem is, there are nearly 50 bags in each kit, and removing the required components from the right bag and rebagging them sounds like it will take a long time, and it seems wasteful as many distributors already have these bagging facilities. It's also not an option to make an order for each kit, because that's looking to be £50 each.

So do any distributors offer the option of splitting each order into little bags? I've already shot off an email to Farnell about this possibility, but I'm not hopeful - I'm wondering if any distributors just offer it as an option on their website somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Digi-Key does this; check [their BOM manager](https://ordering.digikey.com/Help.aspx?WT.z_homepage_link=hp_BOM&id=New%20BOM%20Wizard&site=US&lang=en).

Comment: +1 - this looks neat and perfect for what I want. But I'm worried about Digi-Key in that they say that no taxes are included. I live in the UK, so who do I pay VAT to?

Comment: VAT is paid to the UPS delivery guy on delivery. You can set up a UPS account to avoid this hassle.